# parse_single_sequence_example says number of values != expected

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having a problem deserializing a SequenceExample, using tensorflow 2.4.1. I get this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Name: <unknown>, Key: Names, Index: 0.  Number of values != expected.  values size: 2 but output shape: [] [Op:ParseSequenceExampleV2]
```

When I run this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

feature_list = tf.train.FeatureList(feature=[
    tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[b'foo', b'bar']))
])
feature_lists = tf.train.FeatureLists(feature_list={ 'Names': feature_list })

sequence_example = tf.train.SequenceExample(context=None, feature_lists=feature_lists)

sequence_features = {
    'Names': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
}

_, sequence_data = tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(
    serialized=sequence_example.SerializeToString(),
    context_features=None,
    sequence_features=sequence_features)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I discovered that this example works if I specify a length of 2 here: `sequence_features = { 'Names': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([2], dtype=tf.string) }`. But in general I don't know the number of elements in the serialized array, so that isn't really a solution.